# Convert MongoDb query into Java BasicDbObject

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I need to convert mongodb query into java.
I have "conversations" collection. 
Mongo db query this way and it's work.

```
{
    messages: { source: 1, $elemMatch: { date: { $gte: ISODate("2013-07-25 00:00:00"), $lt: ISODate("2013-08-26 00:00:00")}}}
}
```

And I am tring into java BasicDBObject

```
elemMatch = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject retrievedField = new BasicDBObject();
elemMatch.put("date", new    BasicDBObject("$gte",StartDate).append("$lte",EndDate));
elemMatch.put("source", 1);
BasicDBObject up = new BasicDBObject();
up.put("$elemMatch",elemMatch);
retrievedField.put("messages", up);
DBCursor cursor  = this.dbCollection.find( retrievedField).limit(10);
```

but this code not working

My collection's data is

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f130d6e4b0bf50e9bfc038"),
    "saleId" : 2.43564e+07,
    "saleCode" : "905155440001",
    "randomId" : 9630,
    "creatorId" : 8.21048e+06,
    "recipientId" : 4.83831e+06,
    "creatorType" : 1,
    "returnReasonId" : 11,
    "conversationClosed" : false,
    "operatorCalled" : false,
    "sellerNotified" : false,
    "buyerNotified" : false,
    "operatorCalledDate" : null,
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-25T14:06:14.967Z"),
    "lastUpdateDate" : ISODate("2013-08-15T08:46:10.115Z"),
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "senderId" : 8.21048e+06,
            "source" : 1,
            "seenByBuyer" : true,
            "seenBySeller" : true,
            "seenByOperator" : true,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-07-25T14:06:39.968Z"),
            "messageBody" : "asdad"
        }, 
        {
            "senderId" : 8.21048e+06,
            "source" : 1,
            "seenByBuyer" : true,
            "seenBySeller" : true,
            "seenByOperator" : true,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-07-25T14:06:59.978Z"),
            "messageBody" : "asdasdawdwa"
        }, 
        {
            "senderId" : 0,
            "source" : 4,
            "seenByBuyer" : true,
            "seenBySeller" : true,
            "seenByOperator" : true,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-07-25T14:07:20.044Z"),
            "messageBody" : "ad"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help?

```
Calendar calStartDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calEndDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date StartDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(messageStartDate);
        Date EndDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(messageEndDate);

        calStartDate.setTime(StartDate);
        calEndDate.setTime(EndDate);
        Date sdate = new DateTime(calStartDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),calStartDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), calStartDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),calStartDate.get(Calendar.HOUR),calStartDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();
        Date edate = new DateTime(calEndDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), calEndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), calEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calEndDate.get(Calendar.HOUR), calEndDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
                "messages",
                new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",new BasicDBObject("source", 1).append("date", new BasicDBObject("$gte", sdate).append("$lt", edate)))
        );

        DBCursor cursor  = this.dbCollection.find( query).limit(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell query was not correct anyway. It should be:

```
{
    "messages": { 
       "$elemMatch": { 
          "source": 1,
          "date": { 
              "$gte": ISODate("2013-07-25 00:00:00"),
              "$lt": ISODate("2013-07-26 00:00:00")
         }
       }
   }
}
```

And it helps to follow the same nesting rules so you don't get the flow incorrect:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
    "messages",
    new BasicDBObject(
        "$elemMatch",
        new BasicDBObject( "source", 1 )
            .append( new BasicDBObject(
               "date",
               new BasicDBObject( "$gte", StartDate )
                   .append( "$lt", EndDate )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Make sure that "dates" are of type [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) returned from something like jodatime to be valid for serialization as well. And make sure that are UTC times you are constructing from.

Example:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

Date StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 25, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date StartDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(messageStartDate); StartDate and endDate is this way is it?

Comment: @neoerol No those are strings. You need to pass in a date object like I said. MongoDB stores as a "Date" BSON type and not a string. Use something that produces `java.util.Date` as I said in the answer.

Comment: @neoerol Added a simple example to follow at the end of the answer.